# matplotlib spline adjustment changes tick label visibility

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I've found some odd behavior with `pyplot`. When I run the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = 2 * np.sin(x)

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, sharex=True)

ax0.plot(x, y)
ax1.plot(x, y)

#ax0.spines['top'].set_position(('outward', 0))

plt.show()
```

it produces the plot

[image: Plot without issue (no labels on top subplot x-axis ticks)]

However, uncommenting the `ax0.spines...` line produces *this* plot

[image: Plot with issue (labels on top subplot x-axis ticks)]

Note that on the top subplot, the x-axis has acquired labels on its ticks. Is this the expected behavior (and due to a misunderstanding on my part of the pyplot API), or is this a bug with pyplot?

Note that this is a minimized example of an issue I noticed with some more complex graph formatting code I'm working on. While the `set_position()` call in this case has no effect, in my code I'm actually bumping all spines outwards. I found with my testing, however, that the change in position seems not to have an effect -- rather, it's the fact of calling the `set_position()` function at all.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. When uncommenting the line in question I get the same figure as without it. Also it is not really clear what you expect this line to actually do.

Comment: The line currently does nothing. In the more complex formatting code, the line concerned is `ax0.spines['top'].set_position(('outward', 5))` (and there are corresponding calls for bottom, left, and right spines). I changed the position to 0 mostly because it made the "expected" and "actual" results match in everything but the x-axis labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem localized to matplotlib 2.0.0 -- it's fixed in 2.1.0